# Error while loading MATLAB coder-derived C file in R

Tags: r, c, matlab, classification, ensemble-learning

In an effort to implement a MATLAB Classification Learner ensemble bagged trees prediction function in R for later use in a Shiny app, I used MATLAB coder to generate .C code based on this function. The function generates a single double output based on 6 double inputs. However, there the main ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2.c file is dependent on several other .c files since this function incorporates a classification learner predict function.

To compile the C code, I used the following terminal command:

```
R CMD SHLIB ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2.c
```

Then, to load the shared object file in R I used the following command and got the following error:

```
dyn.load("/Users/BKH03516/Desktop/R files for shinyapps. /codegen/lib/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2.so")
Error in dyn.load("/Users/BKH03516/Desktop/R files for shinyapps. /codegen/lib/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/Users/BKH03516/Desktop/R files for shinyapps. /codegen/lib/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2.so':
  dlopen(/Users/BKH03516/Desktop/R files for shinyapps. /codegen/lib/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2.so, 6): Symbol not found: _CompactEnsemble_ensemblePredict
  Referenced from: /Users/BKH03516/Desktop/R files for shinyapps. /codegen/lib/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/BKH03516/Desktop/R files for shinyapps. /codegen/lib/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2/ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2.so
```

I have limited experience in R and would greatly appreciate any help with this!

Comment: “dependent on several other .c files” Then you must compile all of those .c files l, and link them all together. You cannot expect the other .c files to be found magically by the compiler, they must be part of the compilation command.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thanks! Do you know how I should go about doing this using: "R CMD SHLIB"? The files that are in the main folder coded by matlab (excluding those in the "interface" and "examples" subfolders which I am not sure that I need) are: ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2.c, CompactClassificationTree.c, CompactEnsemble.c, ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2_data.c, ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2_initialize.c, ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2_terminate.c, findNode.c, predictOneWithCache.c, rt_nonfinite.c, rtGetInf.c, rtGetNaN.c, updateCache.c